# How can I display the number of posts?

Tags: asp.net-core

I create a forum and I have a problem: how can I add the number of posts for each category?  I would like to use the viewmodel

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = categoryService.GetAll();
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property to your ViewModel that will retrieve the number of Post's for that Category.

It could look something like this:

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public int PostCount
        {
            get
            {
                return Posts != null ? Posts.Count : 0;
            }
        }
    }
```